# Electron VueJS - Error in build - Failed to register app protocol. ENOENT, \dist_electron\bundled not found in app.asar

Tags: vuejs2, electron, electron-builder

I made a small windows desktop app using Electron and VueJS.

It works fine when i run it with serve:

```
npm run serve:electron
```

However when i build the app using the following command, the app errors out and leaves a blank window.(using the vue-cli-service again)

```
npm run build:electron
```

when i use my console to cd into the .exe file, and run vue-autobot --debug the following error appears:

```
C:\projects\vue-autobot\dist_electron\win-unpacked>
Failed to register app protocol { Error: ENOENT, dist_electron\bundled\ not found in C:\projects\vue-autobot\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar
    at notFoundError (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:108:19)
    at fs.readFile (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:511:16)
    at Function.A.n.protocol.registerBufferProtocol (C:\projects\vue-autobot\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\dist_electron\bundled\background.js:1:160484) code: 'ENOENT', errno: -2 }
```

Boilerplate : 
[drehimself/electron-vue-example](https://github.com/drehimself/electron-vue-example)

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-autobot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:electron": "vue-cli-service build:electron",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "serve:electron": "vue-cli-service serve:electron"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.6",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "electron": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "main": "dist_electron/bundled/background.js"
}
```

This is my background.js ( Electron main file )

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import * as path from 'path'
import { format as formatUrl } from 'url'
import {
  createProtocol,
  installVueDevtools
} from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
if (isDevelopment) {
  // Don't load any native (external) modules until the following line is run:
  require('module').globalPaths.push(process.env.NODE_MODULES_PATH)
}

// global reference to mainWindow (necessary to prevent window from being garbage collected)
let mainWindow

// Standard scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['app'], { secure: true })
function createMainWindow () {
  const window = new BrowserWindow()

  if (isDevelopment) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    window.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) window.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    //   Load the index.html when not in development
    window.loadURL(
      formatUrl({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
      })
    )
  }

  window.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  window.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
    window.focus()
    setImmediate(() => {
      window.focus()
    })
  })

  return window
}

// quit application when all windows are closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // on macOS it is common for applications to stay open until the user explicitly quits
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // on macOS it is common to re-create a window even after all windows have been closed
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow()
  }
})

// create main BrowserWindow when electron is ready
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    await installVueDevtools()
  }
  mainWindow = createMainWindow()
})
```

I'm new to VueJS and new to Electron, and i have no clue at this point what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out. The problem ended up being very simple, but the error just threw me (way) off.

It turns out i had the `on-click` on a lower level than the `href="#"`. This caused my `<body></body>` to be rendered empty.

```
<li>
  <router-link href="#" to="/">
    <span class="label" v-on:click="turnOffSidebar()">Dashboard</span>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="tachometer-alt" />
  </router-link >
</li>
```

Ofcourse the correct solution was simply this:

```
<li>
  <router-link href="#" to="/" v-on:click="turnOffSidebar()">
    <span class="label">Dashboard</span>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="tachometer-alt" />
  </router-link >
</li>
```

Comment: I'm having similar symptoms, and this doesn't seem to explain what the problem was.

Can you explain why you feel this incorrect click handler placement might cause your body to render empty? As far as I can tell, it should still compile and run, it would just narrow your click handling to the span.

Comment: @Appurist-PaulW When the body renders empty, it could be because of Electron's 7 breaking changes. You might want to checkout the [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/breaking-changes.md).  Furthermore, Unlike plain html, this will be compiled as you mentioned. This could also cause a small error to render a blank page. Why this is exactly i dont know. This is most likely the way it is packaged to a single `asar` file. I recommend you check all your structured html and its tags with the electron 7 breaking changes (section about protocol).

Comment: For me this happened on an `a` tag in my electron app that had `#` as `href` and a `@click` event on the same node. The solution was to use `javascript:;` as `href`, instead.